# SELECT by one of multiple columns with index

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [Person].[Address](
       [AddressID] [int] NOT NULL,
       [AddressLine1] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
       [StateProvinceID] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Address_AddressID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
       [AddressID] ASC
    )
    ) 
    GO
```

With this additional non-clustered index.

```
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Address_AddressLine1_StateProvinceID 
    ON   [Person].[Address]
    (
       [AddressLine1] ASC,
       [StateProvinceID] ASC,
    )
    GO
```

I am working with existing app code. The app will pass two parameters to my query, but one of them might equal '-1'. When it does, the intention is to match all rows for that parameter.

The current query looks like this:

```
    Select AddressID, AddressLine1, StateProvinceID
    From Person.Address
    Where ((AddressID = @AddressID) or (@AddressID=-1))
    and ((StateProvinceID = @StateProvinceID) or (@AddressID=-1))
```

This returns the data needed when either @AddressID or @StateProvinceID is equal to '-1', it is essentially ignore (-1=-1 returns TRUE)

The trouble is indexes. It does a scan, not a seek when I do this.

This returns a seek:

```
    Select AddressID, AddressLine1, StateProvinceID
    From Person.Address
    Where AddressID = @AddressID 
    and StateProvinceID = @StateProvinceID
```

...While the current query a MUCH slower scan.

The second query is fast, but doesn't work the way I need it to.

Is there a way to allow for one or the other parameter to be bypassed, while still using an index seek?

Comment: Have you tried this form of a query: (AddressID = -1) OR ((AddressID = @AddressID) AND (StateProvinceID = @StateProvinceID))? Does your first query perform scan on your index or scan on your table?

Comment: You have **no index** on the search parameter you use - on (`AddressID`, `StateProvinceID`) - therefore, no index can be used. Add an index on those two columns (or on `StateProvinceID` alone - `AddressID` will be automatically included, since it's the clustering key) and there's a chance that new index will be used

Comment: When I run the query with the OR statements, I get a SCAN of the "IX_Address_AddressLine1_StateProvinceID" index. When I run the second query with only the AND statement, I get a SEEK of the "PK_Address_AddressID" clustered index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that branching logic in a single SQL statement will always return a SCAN instead of a SEEK.

What I ended up doing to fix this was to write explicit (and ugly) branching logic to choose a SIMPLE query for the conditions I wanted.

In my example, there are two parameters. The goal is that when a given parameter = -1 to match all records, essentially ignoring that parameter in the where clause.

With two parameters, there are 4 possible scenarios.

- parm1 set, parm2 -1 (ignoring)
- parm1 -1 (ignoring), parm2 set
- parm1 set, parm2 set
- parm1 -1 (ignoring), parm2 -1 (ignoring) <--returns ALL rows

So I wrote branching logic with 4 If statements.

If parm1 <> -1 and parm2 = -1

```
 - then do a simple query that only uses parm1
```

If parm1 = -1 and parm2 <> -1

```
 - then do a simple query that only uses parm2
```

etc...

This, while EXTREMELY ugly, returns a SEEK every time. Ugly, but very fast code. The prettier "When, Then, Else" SINGULAR block statement always does a scan, and kills the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE`, `WHEN`, `THEN` in your sql command ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select AddressID, AddressLine1, StateProvinceID
From Person.Address
Where AddressID = CASE WHEN @AddressID = -1 THEN AddressID ELSE @AddressID END AND
      StateProvinceID = CASE WHEN @StateProvinceID = -1 THEN StateProvinceID ELSE @StateProvinceID END
```

Comment: This returns a SCAN of the "IX_Address_AddressLine1_StateProvinceID". I'm trying to avoid a scan, and it seems whatever logic I put into the WHERE clause it turns it into a SCAN.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you update your index that has columns: [AddressLine1] and [StateProvinceID] to [StateProvinceID] and [AddressLine1] (putting StateProvinceID first in the index) the query should use this index and not the full table scan.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that, but I still get a SCAN instead of a SEEK if I use my OR statements, or when I try a CASE statement.

Comment: is it a scan on IX_Address_AddressLine1_StateProvinceID?  this is an index scan.. which should be a lot faster than a table scan.. is the performance still bad?

Comment: Yes, an index SCAN of IX_Address_AddressLine1_StateProvinceID. I know this is better than a table scan, but still MUCH slower than a seek. (like 10-20 times slower in my tests)